# Converting tinyint to string

Tags: c#, wpf

column type is tinyint, i need convert to string, i use `Converter` for xaml

```
Text="{Binding confirmed,Converter={StaticResource UserConverter}}"
```

so

```
class UserConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var listOfInt = value as UInt32[];
                return ""+listOfInt+"";
            }
            return "";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
```

but its wrong, please help me with code :)

Comment: Where have you inherit/implement IValueConverter?

Comment: I forgot, but nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?

A `tinyInt` should be mapped to a `byte`, not a `UInt32[]`.

If your result is an array of tinyInt's try converting to `byte[]`

Comment: If you add a breakpoint within your Convert() method, is it hit? If so what is the value of the 'value' parameter. XamlParseException sounds like an exception with your XAML, verify that your declaration is correct.